# why is my forloop, in my lexical_words function, not comparing the words in my string array('keyWords") with the words in my string iterator?

Tags: c++, regex, list, for-loop

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void lexical_words(string,string*,vector<string> &); // the forloop is not properly   comparing the            words in my "keyWords" with words from the iterator
void lexical_integer(string);
void lexical_operators(string);
void lexical_reals(string);
void lexical_separators(string);
void lexical_identifies(string);

list<string> someWords;

void lexical_integer(string seq)
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("output.txt",ios::app);


    regex digits("(\\d+)");
    regex_iterator<string::iterator> itd(seq.begin(), seq.end(), digits);
    regex_iterator<string::iterator> end;

    for (; itd != end; ++itd)
    {
        cout << itd->str() <<" " <<" integer"<< endl;
        fout<<itd->str()<< " "<<" integer"<<endl;
    }
    fout.close();
}


void lexical_identifier(string seq)
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("output.txt",ios::app);

    regex digits("^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$");
    regex_iterator<string::iterator> itd(seq.begin(), seq.end(), digits);
    regex_iterator<string::iterator> end;

    for (; itd != end; ++itd)
    {
        cout << itd->str() <<" " <<" identifier"<< endl;
        fout<<itd->str()<< " "<<" identifier"<<endl;
    }
    fout.close();
}


void lexical_separators(string seq)
{
ofstream fout;
fout.open("output.txt",ios::app);


regex digits("(\\W)");
regex_iterator<string::iterator> itd(seq.begin(), seq.end(), digits);
regex_iterator<string::iterator> end;

for (; itd != end; ++itd)
{
    cout << itd->str() <<" " <<" Separator"<< endl;
    fout<<itd->str()<< " "<<" Separator"<<endl;
}
fout.close();
    }



   void lexical_reals(string seq)
    {
ofstream fout;
fout.open("output.txt",ios::app);

regex digits("^[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)$");
regex_iterator<string::iterator> itd(seq.begin(), seq.end(), digits);
regex_iterator<string::iterator> end;

for (; itd != end; ++itd)
{
    cout << itd->str() <<" " <<" real number"<< endl;
    fout << itd->str() <<" " <<" real number"<< endl;
}
fout.close();
    } 



   **void lexical_words(string seq,string * keyWords,vector<string>& sVector)
   {
ofstream fout;
fout.open("output.txt",ios::app);
regex words("(\\w+)");
regex_iterator<string::iterator> itd(seq.begin(), seq.end(), words);
regex_iterator<string::iterator> end;
//int size;

//size = sizeof(keyWords);

    for (; itd != end; itd++)
    {   
        for(int k = 0; k < sVector().size;k++)
        {
            if(keyWords[k] == itd->str())
            {
            cout << itd->str() <<" " <<" keyword"<< endl;
            fout << itd->str() <<" " <<" keyword"<< endl;
            }
        }
    }

fout.close();
           }**

      int main()
     {


char operators[] ={'+','-','*','`','!','\\','&','|','~',
'<','>','=',':','%','^'}; 

char separators[] = { '(', ')', '{','}','[', ']',  ';', ':', '"', '?', ',', '.',      '//', '#'}; 

char numbers[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

string keyWords[] = {"while","for","do","if","else","int","double","long","array","break",
    "case","catch","switch","bool","char","class","const","continue","default","delete",
    "enum","event","enum class","explicit","extern","false","finally","float","friend","goto"
    "new","private","protected","static","short","true","void","try","this","struct","throw","signed","cin","cout","using"
"namespace","std"};

    vector<string> sVector;
    sVector.assign(keyWords,keyWords+47);


string line;
ifstream fin;
string fName;
//cout<<"please enter your file name"<<endl;
//cin>>fName;
//fin.open(fName.c_str());
//while(!fin)
//{
    //cout<<"wrong file name"<<endl;
    //cin>>fName;
    fin.open("C:\\Users\\vishal\\Desktop\\tokens.txt");
//}
while(!fin.eof())
{

fin>>line;
lexical_words(line,keyWords,sVector);
lexical_identifier(line);
lexical_separators(line);
lexical_integer(line);
lexical_reals(line);

}
cout<<"The same output has also been created in a file called output.txt"<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

I have written a tokenizer program. I would like to compare the words that I get from the regex iterator to the words in my list called "keyWords", and if they match to output them to the screen. However, for some reason my forloop is not advancing the counter and only the first word of my list "keyWords" , which is "while", is being compared to words generated by the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
size = sizeof(keyWords);
```

as it will return the `sizeof(std::string*)`, and not the number of elements in the array `keyWords`. Either pass in the number of elements in the array as an argument or change to a [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or [`std::array<std::string, N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) which can be queried for its `size()` or you be iterated using `begin()` and `end()`. For example:

```
const std::array<std::string, 2> keyWords = { { "do",
                                                "while" }
                                            };
```

Change function to take a `const std::array<std::string, 2>&` argument instead. You could `typedef` the array for convenience:

```
typedef std::array<std::string, 2> keyword_array_t;
```

Comment: how can i convert my string array to a vector?

Comment: From the `#include <regex>`, I think C++11 features are available?